# How to publish UIImage to Facebook

Tags: facebook, uiimage

I want to publish image from UIImage to Facebook however this code needs imageURL. How?

- (void) publishFeedWithName:(NSString*)name 
               captionText:(NSString*)caption 
                  imageurl:(NSString*)url 
                   linkurl:(NSString*)href
         userMessagePrompt:(NSString*)prompt 
               actionLabel:(NSString*)label
                actionText:(NSString*)text 
                actionLink:(NSString*)link
                  targetId:(NSString*)target{
  [self postFeedWithName:name 
             captionText:caption 
                imageurl:url 
                 linkurl:href 
       userMessagePrompt:prompt
             actionLabel:label
              actionText:text 
              actionLink:link
                targetId:target];
  }

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the image as a JPG or other transmittable file image.  That can be done with UIImageJPEGRepresentation as described about halfway down here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1282830/uiimagepickercontroller-uiimage-memory-and-more

I don't have access right now to the box where I have the Facebook SDK installed and the example app that can upload an image, so I can't tell you the details of how to do that at present.  But the Facebook SDK example package shows you how to do it.

Comment: thank you! if you got any example codes, please feel free to post here, i need it for my project. thanks :))